# Access COM class from PHP

Tags: php, com

I have a problem accessing a COM-class in PHP. I'm using IIS 8 Express, PHP for Windows and Web matrix(setup web sites). I can get the COM-class working in .NET VB-script but not in PHP 5. Also failed in classic ASP. I have tried setting up with `dcomcnfg.exe` in different combinations. Also tried running the PHP-file directly with `php.exe` and get the same results.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    try
    {
        $tcsuser = new COM("TCSApi.TCSUser.1") or die("Can not connect to COM Class");
    }
    catch(com_exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The results is:

> Failed to create COM object `TCSApi.TCSUser.1': Interface not supported